# How does JPA relate to EJB relate to Java EE 6

Tags: tomcat, jpa

I'm a happy Tomcat user, and wish to use the new Java Persistence API. I'm a little confused as to where I should get it from?

I don't find the official documentation regarding my questions very clear.

- Is Java EE 6 something specific to an EJB container, such as JBoss or Glassfish?
- Does this mean that if you have an EE 6 container, it automatically supports JPA?
- Is JPA a specification, or an API?
- Are Hibernate, Kodo or OpenJPA, DataNucleus, EclipseLink, TopLink all implementation of the JPA specification?

The reason I ask is because I don't want to deploy very large files. If the container I'm using supports / contains a JPA API, then I'd rather not deploy one with every application?

I had this idea in my head that Tomcat 7's JAR's may have it?

Answer (score 3):

> Is Java EE 6 something specific to an EJB container, such as JBoss or Glassfish?

Java EE 6 is a specification. It's agnostic as to how that spec is implemented, but generally this is done by an appserver such as the two you mention.

> Does this mean that if you have an EE 6 container, it automatically supports JPA?

Yes. JPA is part of JavaEE v5 and v6.

> Is JPA a specification, or an API?

Both. The spec defines the semantics, the API defines the syntax.

> Are Hibernate, Kodo or OpenJPA, DataNucleus, EclipseLink, TopLink all implementation of the JPA specification?

Yes. Different appservers ship with different JPA implementations.

> If the container I'm using supports / contains a JPA API, then I'd rather not deploy one with every application?

That's the general idea. Use the services that your appserver provides.

> I had this idea in my head that Tomcat 7's JAR's may have it?

I'm not familiar with v7 specifically, but Tomcat isn't a full JavaEE implementation (it provides JSP, servlets, and a couple of other things like JNDI), but not JPA. If you deploy to Tomcat, your application will need to package its own JPA implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use JPA in Tomcat. Currently we are using OPENJPA in Tomcat adding JPA enhancer to the build.  There are also a lot of examples (i.e. http://dev.imanol.me/post/32735636704/tomcat-jpa-hibernate-and-mysql) for setting up Hibernate JPA in Tomcat.